# Distributed locks redis by keys

Tags: java, redis, distributed-system, redisson

I am trying to write a solution in order to avoid writes on database in a system that consumes events in any order.

I have Elasticsearch as a final database, there are documents containing a lot of properties, imagine that:

```
{
  "property01": "value01",
  "property02": "value02",
  "property03": "value03",
  "property04": "value04",
            ...
  "lastUpdate": "datetime"
}
```

The lastUpdate will always be updated when document change.

But I do not consume all data at once, some properties are consumed by separated events.
Like this:

**event01**

```
{
  "key": "myKey",
  "property01": "value01",
  "property02": "value02",
  "eventDate": "datetime"
}
```

**event02**

```
{
  "key": "myKey",
  "property03": "value03",
  "property04": "value04",
  "eventDate": "datetime"
}
```

- We fetch a batch of those *json* at once, usually 10.
- We are using AWS Lambda do process it, so we can have multiples lambdas fetching data.
- We can have in the queue, two (or more) events data from the same event+key in different order.

**What I thought**

Using redis as database to store the key of the event and eventData:
A **pseudocode**:

```
var newEvent = {
  "key": "myKey",
  "property03": "valuex",
  "property04": "valuex",
  "eventDate": "2022-08"
  "eventName": "event01"
}
```

---

```
class ConcurrencyOperation {
   List<String> toCommit;
   List<String> toDiscard;
}


public Operations check(List<String> events) {
   var concurrencyOperation = new ConcurrencyOperation();

   for (String newEvent : events) {

     var currentEventDate = newEvent.eventDate;
     var currentEventKey = newEvent.eventName + "-" + newEvent.key;
     
     // get the last event info
     var lastEventKeyDate = redis.get(currentEventKey);
     
     if (lastEventKeyDate == null || currentEventDate > lastEventKeyDate) {
       redis.set(currentEventKey, currentEventDate);
       concurrencyOperation.addToCommit(newEvent);
     } else {
      concurrencyOperation.addToDiscard(newEvent);
    }
  }
}
```

I know that calling a get to compare I can have race problems.

I really need to "lock" using the pattern eventKey, so I can check by event+key.

**Question**
Is it better to use redis with lock? Will be possible to do something like that in order to avoid *unorder* events but even using parallels processing?

**Note:** I would like to use Java because is the most common language for us, and we can reuse the solution. Java + Redisson.

Answer (score 0):

I think to you are describing a typical use case of a redis stream. Indeed, this is a data type that conserves event order and that can be consumed by numerous workers, in an asynchronous and concurrent manner.

You can [create a consumer group](https://redis.io/commands/xgroup-createconsumer/) with multiple consumers. Events in the stream key will be distributed to a worker among the consumer group, which will have to acknowledge the treatment of the said event so that it (the event) will not be distributed again to another worker.

You can create multiple consumers groups to process events for different purposes.

Note to self: You have to dispatch events among multiple streams (among multiple redis instances) in a Redis cluster if you want to have more that ~100k-200k events/sec.